# Grunt cssmin and timestamp filename

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I'm trying to set up a grunt task that outputs a minified css file and changes the file name with a timestamp.

My Gruntfile looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  //project configurations
  grunt.initConfig({

    cssmin: {
      target: {
        src: ["css/aw2018.css", ],
        dest: "dist/aw2018.min.css"
      }
    }

    replace: {
      foo: {
        options: {
          variables: {
            'timestamp': '<%= new Date().getTime() %>'
          },
          force: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'css/',
          src: ['*.css/*.js'],
          dest: 'dist/',
          ext: '.<%= new Date().getTime() %>.js'
        }]
      }
    }

  });

  //load cssmin plugin
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

  //create default task
  grunt.registerTask("default", ["cssmin"]);
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'replace');

};
```

But I get an error of 
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm ultimately trying to achieve:

1. Minify a css file
2. Add a timestamp to the end of the file name.

I would like to have it work for any css file in a folder but keep them separate. For instance, lets say I have `aw2018.css` and `aw2017.css`. I would like both of them to run through the task and then be output to their own individual minified css file with the timestamp of `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` at the end of the filename.

Comment: If you're trying to do this using [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace) then it's the wrong tool. That plugin is for replacing text strings in the _contents_ of files and not for filenames. The [`timestamp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace#timestamp) option for that plugin is  for preserving [atime](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stats_atime) and [mtime](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stats_mtime) when copying files - it has nothing to do with appending a timestamp to a filename. Try to describe in your question what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: I think there is a basic syntax error, a comma missing after defining the `cssmin` task. SO without that comma, `grunt.initConfig` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by utilizing grunt's [`rename`](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) function when building the files object dynamically, instead of using another task.

The documentation describes grunts `rename` function as follows:

> `rename` Embeds a customized function, which returns a string containing the new destination and filename. This function is called for each matched `src` file (after extension renaming and flattening).

Inside the body of the `rename` function is where you add your custom logic to append a timestamp to each filename.

The following `Gruntfile.js` configuration shows how to achieve this:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  var path = require('path'); // Load nodes built-in `path` module.

  // Obtain local timestamp formatted as: YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS
  var tzOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  var timeStamp = (new Date(Date.now() - tzOffset)).toISOString().slice(0, -1)
      .replace(/\.[\w\W]+?$/, '') // Delete from dot to end.
      .replace(/\:|\s|T/g, '-');  // Replace colons, spaces, and T with hyphen.

  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      timestamp: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'css/',
          src: ['aw2017.css', 'aw2018.css'],
          dest: 'dist/',

          /**
           * Grunt rename function generates new destination filepath,
           # adds timestamp, and new min.css extension to the file name.
           # (https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#the-rename-property)
           #
           * @param {String} dest - The path to the desination directory.
           * @param {String} src - The path to the source directory.
           * @returns {String} New dest path with time-stamped filename.
           */
          rename: function(dest, src) {
            var fileExt = path.extname(src),
              fileName = path.basename(src, fileExt),
              dirName = path.dirname(src),
              newFileExt = ['.min', fileExt].join(''),
              newFileName = [fileName, '-', timeStamp, newFileExt].join(''),
              newDestPath = path.join(dest, dirName, newFileName);

            return newDestPath;
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin:timestamp']);
};
```

---

#### Additional info:

1. Firstly, in the `Gruntfile.js` above, we load the nodejs built-in [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module via the line reading.

   ```js
   var path = require('path');
   ```

   This module is used later in the `rename` function to help create the new time-stamped filename, and ascertain the destination filepath to be `return`'ed:
2. We then create a local timestamp formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` via the lines reading:

   ```js
   var tzOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
   var timeStamp = (new Date(Date.now() - tzOffset)).toISOString().slice(0, -1)
       .replace(/\.[\w\W]+?$/, '') // Delete from dot to end.
       .replace(/\:|\s|T/g, '-');  // Replace colons, spaces, and T with hyphen.
   ```

   Note: We assign the generated timestamp to the `timeStamp` variable outside of any grunt task(s) to ensure all resultant filenames get the same timestamp.

   The date/time format will be based on your local timezone and not UTC (Coordinated Universal Time).
3. We then reconfigure your `cssmin` task to [build the files object dynamically](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) instead of utilizing the [compact format](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format). By configuring the task this way we get access to the `rename` function.

---

#### Further usage and modifications to the current config:

1. The `Gruntfile.js` configuration provided above takes a two source CSS files, named `aw2017.css` and `aw2018.css` from the following directory structure:

   ```
   .
   └── css
       ├── aw2017.css
       └── aw2018.css
   ```

   After running the `grunt` command via your CLI, it outputs both minified (time-stamped) `.css` files to the new `dist` directory. Resulting as this:

   ```
   .
   ├── css
   │   ├── aw2017.css
   │   └── aw2018.css
   └── dist
       ├── aw2017-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
       └── aw2018-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
   ```
2. However, if you want to also include the source `css` folder in the `dist` directory like this:

   ```
   .
   ├── css
   │   ├── aw2017.css
   │   └── aw2018.css
   └── dist
       └── css
           ├── aw2017-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
           └── aw2018-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
   ```

   then you need to change the values of the `cwd` and `src` properties in the `cssmin` task to this:

   ```js
   // ...
   cwd: '.',
   src: ['css/aw2017.css', 'css/aw2018.css'],
   // ...
   ```

---

#### Minifying and time-stamping multiple `.css` files using a glob pattern

Currently, in your question, you seem to only want to *minify* two `.css` file, namely `aw2017.css` and `aw2018.css`.

However, if you wanted to *minify* (and time-stamp) many `.css` files found in the `css` directory, however many levels deep, you can utilize a [globbing pattern](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). For example, lets say your source `css` directory looks like this:

```
.
└── css
   ├── a.css
   ├── b.css
   ├── foo
   │   ├── bar
   │   │   └── c.css
   │   └── d.css
   └── quux
       └── e.css
```

...and if you change the values of the `cwd` and `src` properties in your `cssmin` task to this:

```js
// ...
cwd: '.',
src: ['css/**/*.css'],
// ...
```

Your resultant output will be something like this:

```
.
├── css
│   └── ...
└── dist
    └── css
        ├── a-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
        ├── b-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
        ├── foo
        │   ├── bar
        │   │   └── c-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
        │   └── d-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
        └── quux
            └── e-2018-05-09-08-35-57.min.css
```